# Regarding OAuth 2.0: Are 3rd Party Cookies Enabled a dependency?

Tags: web-services, cookies, authentication, oauth-2.0

When blocking 3rd Party cookies using Google Chrome (latest), build 27 Win7/PC, I've seen that almost all OAuth logins from other sites don't work, with the exception of signing in with G+.  I've already signed in with Google though, so that cookie exists.

- Is this behavior that is actually a dependency of OAuth2.0, requiring
  3rd-party cookies to be enabled?
- Is it a consequence of the prevailing implementation of
  OAuth?
- Is this something client-dependent?
- Is this resulting from how Chrome defines what "third-party cookies" are?

Thank you all for your help and time! I can't seem to find any sources that clarify the issue for me.

Comment: Chrome on Mac gets the same problem with G+. I also cannot find any articles or sources that clarify what's going on.

Comment: I cannot find any direct corroboration of this hypothesis, but I suspect sites solve this by doing OAuth on the back-end server-side, then send a 302/Redirect to the client and set the cookies directly from their own domain. I suspect trying to do OAuth client-side will always fail when 3rd party cookies are blocked in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

For web applications, some sort of storage local storage is required ("MUST...") by the OAuth 2.0 spec as part of the defense against Cross-site request forgery (CSRF). The spec suggests cookies or HTML5 local storage specifically, with cookies being a prevalent implementation as your observations show.

Referencing [RFC 6749 - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) we find (**emphasis added**):

> 10. Security Considerations

> As a flexible and extensible framework, OAuth's security
> considerations depend on many factors.  The following sections
> provide implementers with security guidelines focused on the three
> client profiles described in Section 2.1: web application,
> user-agent-based application, and native application.

...

> 10.12.  Cross-Site Request Forgery

> Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) is an exploit in which an attacker
> causes the user-agent of a victim end-user to follow a malicious URI
> (e.g., provided to the user-agent as a misleading link, image, or
> redirection) to a trusting server (usually established via the
> presence of a valid session cookie).

> A CSRF attack against the client's redirection URI allows an attacker
> to inject its own authorization code or access token, which can
> result in the client using an access token associated with the
> attacker's protected resources rather than the victim's (e.g., save
> the victim's bank account information to a protected resource
> controlled by the attacker).

> **The client MUST implement CSRF protection for its redirection URI.**
> This is typically accomplished by requiring any request sent to the
> redirection URI endpoint to include a value that binds the request to
> the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g., a hash of the session
> cookie used to authenticate the user-agent).  The client SHOULD
> utilize the "state" request parameter to deliver this value to the
> authorization server when making an authorization request.

> Once authorization has been obtained from the end-user, the
> authorization server redirects the end-user's user-agent back to the
> client with the required binding value contained in the "state"
> parameter.  The binding value enables the client to verify the
> validity of the request by matching the binding value to the
> user-agent's authenticated state.  **The binding value used for CSRF
> protection MUST contain a non-guessable value (as described in
> Section 10.10), and the user-agent's authenticated state (e.g.,
> session cookie, HTML5 local storage) MUST be kept in a location
> accessible only to the client and the user-agent (i.e., protected by
> same-origin policy).**